# Minimum number of "swaps" needed to sort two arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic, tuples

This is a challenge question I've been having problems solving optimally ([my attempt with failure analysis](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingCNWYCU-E29/)).

Given two arrays of equal length `A = [1,8,12,11], B = [7,3,10,15]`, sort them in ascending order by only performing swaps.

A `swap` means replacing element at index `i` in `A` with the corresponding `B` element and vice versa.

The above example can resolve to `A = [1,3,12,15], B = [7,8,10,11]` or `A = [1,3,10,11], B = [7,8,12,15]` both with `2 swaps`. However there are cases where solutions have different number of swaps, here the minimum is chosen and if it is not possible, return `-1`

How would I go about solving this perfectly in O(N)?

Comment: Some approaches might give `A = [90, 2, 3, 4], B = [1, 91, 92, 93]` as three swaps minimum, when the real answer is one swap at the first position.  I suspect that if there are more than half the positions swapped, the real answer is actually `arraySize - swaps`, though I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let `f(i, swap)` represent the minimum number of swaps achievable up to index `i` where `swap` is a boolean representing if the elements at index `i` are to be swapped. Then:

```
f(i, false) = min(
  f(i - 1, false) if A[i] >= A[i-1] and B[i] >= B[i-1] else Infinity,

  f(i - 1, true) if A[i] >= B[i-1] and B[i] >= A[i-1] else Infinity
)

f(i, true) = min(
  1 + f(i - 1, false) if B[i] >= A[i-1] and A[i] >= B[i-1] else Infinity,

  1 + f(i - 1, true) if B[i] >= B[i-1] and A[i] >= A[i-1] else Infinity
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tested your code against the challenge site, but it seems logically similar to what I tried ([cleaned version of my attempt](https://ideone.com/FhFl0X)). How does this work when mine failed the greedy test case i.e. where did I mess up.